# 2022 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

## The 2022 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

### [2022 Moderator Election](https://english.stackexchange.com/election)

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Answer (score 9):

One bit of information voters might find helpful that I don't see linked anywhere obvious in the election pages is [how the candidate score is calculated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252643/273494):

> The Candidate Score can range from 0 to 40, and is calculated as
> follows:
>
> - 1 point for each 1000 reputation up to 20,000 reputation for a maximum of 20 points.
> - 1 point each for Moderation badges - Civic Duty, Cleanup, Deputy, Electorate, Marshal, Reviewer, Sportsmanship, Steward - for a maximum
>   of 8 points.
> - 1 point each for Editing badges - Copy Editor, Explainer, Organizer, Refiner, Strunk and White, Tag Editor - for a maximum of 6 points.
> - 1 point each for Participation badges - Constituent, Convention, Enthusiast, Investor, Quorum, Yearling - for a maximum of 6 points.
>   For badges that can be awarded multiple times only 1 point is granted
>   for each badge type, thus ensuring a maximum score of 40 points.
>
> Stats are calculated based on the current state of the candidate, so
> scores on past elections will not reflect the state of the candidates
> at the time the election was run.

(The original post has links to each of the badges that I didn't reproduce here)

Answer (score 1):

Is it the case that we cannot nominate other people?  Only ourselves?

Comment: Yep, that's how it works. (Mods are volunteers, not volunteered.) You might be able to give some encouragement if you see them around chat or something though.

Comment: @Laurel I love that use of the passive: *volunteers, not volunteered*, both working as predicates! One might argue that "volunteered" is a passive used as a modifier and is therefore a predicate adjective, but I won't go farther than loving how both work as predicates. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I missed this during the comment period, but I see now one candidate, Lawrence, made [the following comment in their questionnaire responses](https://english.stackexchange.com/election/6?tab=election#post-586325):

> **Mods can also reverse unfair downvotes** and privately communicate with repeat offenders when flagged, but that probably doesn't have a lot of impact on retaining the native speaker. What would likely help more is for mods to delete nasty comments.

(emphasis mine)

This is news to me; as far as I know mods cannot reverse downvotes; this is a system process that happens either automatically (e.g. serial voting reversal) or by manual intervention by CMs/employees with database access.

Was this a misconception, a reference to something else, or can moderators on EL&U actually do this for some reason?

Comment: It's likely referring to serial voting. And you're right, it's a system remedy/fix. Although if a user's account is deleted by a moderator the votes associated with that account are annulled which means any DV (and UV) that were awarded are reversed so in a sense... MSE: [Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted)

Comment: Mari-Lou A is correct that serial voting (from one user to another) is what mods can help reverse (by escalating to a CM when it looks like a real pattern missed by the script, see the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/323179)). The only other type of voting that I have seen reversed is [automated voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362020/323179), where someone used a script to get voting badges.

Comment: @Laurel Thanks for clarifying the mechanism by which these things take place. I stand corrected.

Comment: I’ve now deleted the reference to mods reversing votes.